# kafka consumer polling timeout

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am working with Kafka and trying to consume data from it. From the below line, I can poll the data from Kafka.

```
  while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<byte[], <byte[]> records = consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    for (ConsumerRecord<byte[], <byte[]> record : records) {
        // retrieve data
    }
  }
```

My question is what is the benefit I am getting by providing `Long.MAX_VALUE` as the timeout as compared to if I provide `200` as the timeout. What is the best practice for the system that will be running production.

Can anyone explain me the difference of high timeout vs low timeout and which should be use in production system?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Setting MAX_VALUE is sort of a synchronous message consuming, waiting forever until we got something returned back from the poll, while setting to a lower value gives you a chance that you can decide to do something else other than awaiting. Which should be used depends on your actual scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What are the things we can do if we set a lower value instead of waiting? I cannot think of any scenario for this. Can you help me understand what are the things we can do or we should do in the production system if we set a lower timeout value? And what do you recommend?

Comment: If you want to break from the loop using a flag or just have some periodic tasks outside the loop to execute. KafkaConsumer offers wakeup method to interrupt the consumer thread so actually you could still achieve this even using long poll timeout.

Comment: Yeah but my question is what are the things people do instead of waiting on long timeout? Is there any case where people do stuff?

Comment: If you don't have any periodic task to execute during message consuming, then setting whatever value has less importance.

Comment: I see so if I set timeout as Long.MAX_VALUE then there is no issue with kafka or consumer code that I should be concerned about instead of it will wait forever to get the data? correct?

Comment: With timeout set to MAX_VALUE, consumer will wait forever to get the data. However such a pattern is preferred by some people:  Set to MAX_VALUE to poll messages and call wakeup to break from the loop.

Comment: Yeah that's the pattern I am using as well. I have another question related to running multiple kafka consumer on the same box [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072666/how-to-run-multiple-kafka-consumers-on-the-same-box-independent-of-each-other). See if you can help me out.